# bash + how to capture the version from rpm

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed, grep

this is the way when I try to get the Kafka version

```
rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_"
kafka_2_6_5_0_292-1.0.0.2.6.5.0-292.noarch
```

Kafka version is 1.0 , so I did the following in order to cut the Kafka version

```
 rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_" | sed s'/-/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-3
 1.0              <-----   results
```

above cli seems to be not so elegant and long syntax

can we do it better , maybe with Perl or Python one liner command  ?

Comment: You can use `rpm -qa kafka* | cut -d'-' -f2` for simplicity.

Comment: this syntax not right , you must use rpm -qa | grep .....

Comment: Why would you use `grep` when `rpm` can do grep for you?

Comment: The glob * is special to the shell so it needs to be quoted/escaped, and yes `rpm` should support the glob *, wild card/ patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refactoring your code

```
rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_" | sed s'/-/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-3
```

1st step: use `AWK`'s `FS` (Field Seperator) instead preprocessing in `sed`

```
rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}{print $2}' | cut -c 1-3
```

2nd step: register `{print $2}` action to lines matching description rather than filtering it with `grep`

```
rpm -qa | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}/^kafka_/{print $2}' | cut -c 1-3
```

3rd step: use `AWK`'s `substr` function in place of `cut -c`

```
rpm -qa | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-"}/^kafka_/{print substr($2,1,3)}'
```

Disclaimer: my answer assumes you want behavior exactly like your original code, even if possibly unexpected i.e. it does get first 3 characters of version parts, regardless of how many digits are in 2nd part so for example for `1.15.0.2.6.5.0-292` it does yield `1.1`

Answer (score 5):

You may use a single `awk`:

```sh
rpm -qa |
awk -F- '/^kafka_/ && split($2, a, /\./) >= 1 {print a[1] "." a[2]}'

1.0
```

Comment: we get the results as --> kafka.
1.0    , but we need only the version "1.0" without kafka word

Comment: ok, what is output of `rpm -qa | awk -F- '/kafka/ {print $2}` command?

Comment: kafka
1.0.0.2.6.5.0

Comment: And if you run `rpm -qa | awk -F- '/^kafka_/ {print $2}` ?

Comment: but please remember we want short syntax then the syntax - " rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_" | sed s'/-/ /g' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-3"

Comment: if I run  rpm -qa | awk -F- '/^kafka_/ {print $2}'
   ,  the n I get 1.0.0.2.6.5.0

Comment: yes now we get just 1.0 as should be , ( but can we do it more shorter> )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236639/discussion-between-jessica-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 4):

Please, many tools about packages return data with different formats.
`rpm` command is a tool where the outputs are different between the tool version and system (GNU/Linux, AIX...)...

So, when you work with `rpm` command in a script, never use `-q` option alone.
Use the `--queryformat` (shortly `--qf`, with two `-`) to specify the output.

See `man rpm` for more information.

Example:

```sh
$ rpm -q --qf "%{NAME}:%{VERSION}" firefox
firefox:91.0.1
```

Tags are specified like this: `%{...}`

Tag names are obtained with `rpm --querytags` command.

Example with unknow/partial name of package:

```sh
$ rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}:%{VERSION}\n" | grep '^kernel'
kernel-srpm-macros:1.0
kernel-headers:5.13.3
kernel-core:5.13.12
kernel-modules:5.13.12
kernel:5.13.12
kernel-modules-extra:5.13.12
```

Note:

- `\n` is used to separate all packages 'name:version' couples

Answer (score 3):

Does this `sed` work?

```
rpm -qa | grep '^kafka_' | sed 's/[a-z0-9_]*-\(...\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: you forget the rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_"

Comment: @jessica Indeed. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

```
if k=$(rpm -qa | grep "^kafka_")
then
  if [[ ${k#*-} =~ ^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+ ]]
  then
    k_version=$BASH_REMATCH
  else
    echo "can not determine kafka version from '$k'"
  fi
else
  echo "No kafka in rpm"
fi
```

The idea here is to remove everything from the version string up to the dash and then use a regexp to get the version part.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, sending output of `rpm -qa` command as a standard input to `awk` code. In `awk` program setting field aeparator to `-` OR `.` and `OFS` to `.`. Then in main program checking if a line starts from `kafka_` then print 2nd and 3rd fields of it as per shown samples.

```
rpm -qa | awk -F'-|\\.' 'BEGIN{OFS="."} /^kafka_/{print $2,$3}'
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done entirely with (GNU) `grep`.

```sh
grep -oP '^kafka_[^-]*-\K\d+\.\d+'
```

For example,

```
$ echo kafka_2_6_5_0_292-1.0.0.2.6.5.0-292.noarch | grep -oP '^kafka_[^-]*-\K\d+\.\d+'
1.0
```

But since you asked for Perl or Python,

```sh
perl -ne'print "$&\n" if /^kafka_[^-]*-\K\d+\.\d+/'
```